# Function readLAS not found

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

In spite of having the packages "rLiDAR" and "lidR" already installed in my computer, and having R Studio updated, when I use the function readLAS(), it doesn´t work. What could be the problem?

My line of code:

```
LAS<-readLAS(lasfile,short=TRUE)
Error: could not find function "readLAS"
```

Comment: Do you have any error message ?

Comment: I have added the code I typed in and the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the package is probably not installed properly and/or the required *magrittr* package is missing (if you are using *lidR*).

```
install.packages("lidR")
install.packages("magrittr")
library(lidR)
las = readLAS("yourpath/yourfile.las")
summary(las)
```

I'm pretty sure the short=TRUE option is only available in the *rLidar* package, not *lidR*.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/lidR.pdf

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rLiDAR/rLiDAR.pdf